# What is the idiomatic way of generating a stream of number in Elixir?

Tags: streaming, generator, elixir

Currently I have the following using generators:

```
(for i <- 999..100, j <- i..100, into: [], do:  i * j)
|> Stream.filter(&(palindromic?(&1)))
|> Enum.sort
|> List.last
```

Is there a way to generate a stream of products instead?

Comment: I can understand the feeling that there "must be some easier way" but I don't think your solution is all that bad, FWIW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what we need to do:

- for each number *i* between 999 and 100
- for each number *j* between *i* and 100
- take product of *i* * *j*

The simplest way to generate such a nested enumeration is to generate a nested list of lists and later flatten it, or use the `flat_map` function right away:

```
Stream.flat_map(999..100, fn i -> Stream.map(i..100, fn j -> j * i end) end)
```